# Whenever I try to edit code in Microsoft visual studio, it's replaced instead

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I found a mistake in my code, so I went to the line and tried to fix it, but then my code was replaced instead of edited. I did fix the code after painstakingly copying and pasting everything, but I shouldn't do this every time I want to edit the code.
[If you didn't understand what I'm saying, click this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qD2s.gif)

Comment: Press the "Insert" button on your keyboard.

Comment: notice the `OVR` in your status bar

Answer (score 1):

In the bottom right corner of Visual Studio you can spot `OVR`. That means you're in the text overwrite mode. Press the Insert-button on your keyboard and you'll switch back to insert mode (`INS`) which is what you're looking for.

Comment: How were you able to post an answer after it was closed?

Comment: I think I just posted my answer a short moment before.

Comment: You posted 65 seconds after it was closed. I guess it wasn't closed fast enough.

Comment: Well, that's strange  no idea ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @gunr2171 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible

Comment: Thx for the info, Alexei!